# Is the weather report ever incorrect?

Tags: stardew-valley

I checked the TV on my last day of Spring - Year 1 and it said that it would rain tomorrow. SCORE! I can prep fields to start planting right away tomorrow (well, after the seed shop opens). After spending the time tilling the soil and fertilizing, I go to sleep, excited to jump into Summer without having to water day 1.

Overnight there was an event that shook things up.

> [From what I can find online](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=634772017) (Spoilers Guide) the earthquake always happens end of Spring - Year 1.

Not only that, it wasn't raining the next day!

Now I'm beginning to doubt if I checked the weather correctly.

Is the weather report ever incorrect? 
Was this because of the other event that happened overnight or that the season changed? 
What other events might cause the weather to be different than what the TV says? Did I just fail to remember what the friendly weather person told me?

Comment: On my very first day (day 1), the TV told me it'd rain the next day, but it actually rained on day 3 instead of day 2. I'm not quite sure if I just misinterpreted the forecast, though.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, except it was windy weather instead of rain. I think its only wrong in corner cases like this. When the seasons change there's a new set of possible weather conditions.

Comment: The only time I've *noticed* it being "wrong" was when I checked it after midnight and it gave me the *next* next day's weather, so it was actually right. … Though come to think, that may count as a bug worth reporting, since you can get two days' weather that way.

Comment: (…and of course, I haven't been able to reproduce it since writing that comment.)

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience I can confirm that on multiple occasions weather report was wrong about today's weather.
Both with wrongly forecasting rain (when a sunny day actually happened) and with failing to forecast it (sunny forecast with an actual rain).

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the weather report says it's going to be sunny, but the next day it's raining.